# Python raises a KeyError (for an out of dictionary key) even though the key IS in the dictionary

Tags: python, exception, dictionary, key

I'm getting a KeyError for an out of dictionary key, even though I know the key IS in fact in the dictionary. Any ideas as to what might be causing this?

```
print G.keys()
```

returns the following:

```
['24', '25', '20', '21', '22', '23', '1', '3', '2', '5', '4', '7', '6', '9', '8', '11', '10', '13', '12', '15', '14', '17', '16', '19', '18']
```

but when I try to access a value in the dictionary on the next line of code...

```
for w in G[v]:    #note that in this example, v = 17
```

I get the following error message:

```
KeyError: 17
```

Comment: One more thing worthy of note, I've tried accessing different key values (1, 2, 3, etc.) and still get the same results.

Answer (score 28, accepted):

That's simple, `17 != '17'`

Comment: wow I feel like an idiot. I'm reading these values from a file, for some reason this didn't occur to me - thanks!

Comment: Smells like a design flaw to me.

Comment: @tchrist absence of implicit casts of ints to strings as a design flaw in the language?

Answer (score 5):

The keys are strings, you are trying to access them as ints.

Comment: So?  Dumb that that should matter.  This isn’t Java, you know!

Comment: @tchrist: Wrong. Python is strongly typed... as it should be. This isn't PHP, you know! (Yuck.)

Answer (score 3):

try with v = '17'. You must convert your int to string